# How to pass a params from view into controller and save it into a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am working on this rails project. I am trying to get an input from the view and pass it into the controller, so it can be saved into a variable for later use.

I have my view layer in `/views/welcome/index.html.erb` with the following :

```
<div class="locator-input">
  <%= text_field_tag :user_input %>
  <%= submit_tag "Get started" %>
</div>
```

and the controller in `/controller/welcome_controller.rb`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def locator
    @user_input = params['user_input']
  end
end
```

and `routes.rb` here

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

so when I go ahead and hit submit, I get this error:

[image: Ugly error !]

I know this error has something to do with `routes.rb` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

My ultimate goal is to get user input, pass it into the controller and save it into a variable to I can use it with my model later on.

I will greatly appreciate some guidance from our experts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The route generate with `root` expects only `GET` requests. But your form sends a `POST` request.

To solve this just add the following to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
root 'welcome#index'
match '/', to: 'welcome#index', via: [:post]
```

Comment: Okay I got a nice redirection to '/' after I enter an input. How can I check if what I have entered as input is actually stored into the the variable :user_input ? in ruby a simple puts "#{@user_input}" will do but I'm new in rails

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the field in a form

```
<div class="locator-input">
  <%= form_tag locator_welcome_path %>
    <%= text_field_tag :user_input %>
    <%= submit_tag "Get started" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You also need to create a route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :welcome, controller: :welcome do
    post :locator
  end

  root 'welcome#index'    
end
```

This will generate

```
locator_welcome POST   /welcome/locator(.:format)                                                                                                  welcome#locator
```